# Is an oscillating multi-tool a good option for detailed sanding?

Tags: power-tools, sanding

I am just wondering if these tools would be we suited for small spaces and sanding in corners.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've got a corded and a cordless oscillating multi tool, and they're amazing for corners, since the sanding pads for them are triangular with 60° corners.

There are a few drawbacks that will keep you from using it as your default go-to sander though:

- They have a relatively small surface area.
- They usually oscillate in a 3° arc, which will be more likely to leave noticeable cross grain scratches than a random orbital sander.
- They don't have holes for dust collection, but this can be remedied since you can buy a dust collection adapter for many of them.

Comment: Would also like to point out that the center of the pad moves the least so sanding can be less efficient in the middle of the pad ( At least on mine it is.)

Answer (score 7):

It's ok for getting into really tight spaces where a normal mouse sander won't fit, but as Doresoom mentioned, it produces an arc-shaped scratch pattern. Also because of the tool's shape and the tiny surface area of the sanding pad, it can be difficult to keep it oriented flat against a surface.

Be sure to run the tool at a lower speed (and use a dust collection adapter if possible), otherwise the hook-and-loop sanding pad's hooks will melt.

Comment: I didn't think that it would happen but I wrecked a pad by using too much pressure. The paper pulled away from the hook and loop. Made it useless. Thankfully I had other pads and the attachment was still in good shape.

Answer (score 5):

Not to suggest that an oscillating multi tool is not good for this type of sanding but *small spaces and sanding in corners* can mean different things.

Just to have another suggestion for these types of scenarios there are such things as contour sanding blocks/grips that are designed to hold paper to a shape. Depending on how tight your corner is you might have more luck with something like this.

[image]

<sup>Image from [LeeValley](https://www.leevalley.com/en-ca/shop/tools/supplies/sanding/accessories/20183-contour-sanding-grips)</sup>

Sure there are commercial products which work well. I find myself wrapping sanding paper around scrap wood all the time albeit mostly for right angles.

Answer (score 3):

The tool manufacturers seem to think so, as every one I've owned has came with a sanding pad mounting system.

I've used mine to get into the inside back corners of furniture that I'm stripping / refinishing, it did tolerably well.